# EF allow spaces

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I was wondering if there was a way to configure a Model value to accept spaces as a valid entry.  Currently, when a user enters spaces, I get a error indicating the Model is invalid.

The model is defined as -

```
public class OrderItemCustomizationOption : BaseModel
{
    [Required()]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public int CustomizationOptionId { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderItem OrderItem { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomizationOption CustomizationOption { get; set; }
}
```

I need the "Value" field to allow spaces as valid.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are creating the instance of the model?

Comment: `Required` is nothing to do with EF, it's for model validation. Remove that and add custom validation instead by extending `IValidatableObject`

Comment: @Joseph EF uses it for specifying nullability.

Comment: @hvd yes - you're right. I concur Adriano Repetti's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RequiredAttribute` considers strings containing white-spaces as empty. You can avoid this setting `AllowEmptyString` to `true` (and probably also `ConvertEmptyStringToNulls` to `false`) but this will vanish most of what this attribute represents.

In general you may use `MinLengthAttribute` to validate length of strings and arrays (regardless of their content):

```
[MinLength(1)]
[Column(Order = 4)]
[StringLength(50)]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

However in this case you're using a string specific validation attribute `StringLength`, it has a property you can use to specify minimum required length. Same code can then be better rewritten as:

```
[Column(Order = 4)]
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
public string Value { get; set; }
```